# WorkManager 2.0.1 to 2.1.0 api change "setInitialDelay" when migrating from V1

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I have a android library which uses `Work manager` to handle task schedulings. For **backward compatibity**, I made the library using support library.

since `setInitialDelay` is moved to parent class in WorkManager v2.1.0, if the library uses this (while using WorkManager v1 and support library), the `Jetifier` will make WorkManger v1 just like WorkManager v2.0.1 and not v2.0.2. So this will cause the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 No virtual method setInitialDelay(JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Landroidx/work/OneTimeWorkRequest$Builder;
 in class Landroidx/work/OneTimeWorkRequest$Builder;
```

The old workManager (2.0.1) code is like this:

```
abstract class WorkRequest {
    abstract static class Builder<B extends Builder, W extends WorkRequest> {
    }
}

class OneTimeWorkRequest extends WorkRequest {
   static class Builder extends WorkRequest.Builder<Builder, OneTimeWorkRequest> {
       public @NonNull Builder setInitialDelay(long duration, @NonNull TimeUnit timeUnit) {
          ....
       }
  }
}
```

And the new one (^2.1.0) is :

```
abstract class WorkRequest {
    abstract static class Builder<B extends Builder, W extends WorkRequest> {
         public @NonNull B setInitialDelay(long duration, @NonNull TimeUnit timeUnit) {
              ...
         }
    }
}

class OneTimeWorkRequest extends WorkRequest {
   static class Builder extends WorkRequest.Builder<Builder, OneTimeWorkRequest> {
  }
}
```

**TL;DR**

If **developer uses workManager `v2.1.0`**, what will happen to **libraries that have WorkManager v1** and use Jetifer to transform to v2?

Comment: Any update on this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the API change is a breaking and to resolve this, you must migrate the project to **AndroidX**.

Further changes of `androidx.workmanager` will not consider compatibility to `android.arch` artifact.